# Determine start date within time series

Tags: r, time-series, signals, theory, noise

I hope you're doing well! I have a theoretical time-series analysis problem I hope that you can help me sort out.

To start, you'll find a reproducible example of my dataset below. **Date** is in a daily timescale. **Q25** is 25th or lower quartile of my non-transformed data, **Q75** is the 75th or upper quartile of my non-transformed data, **fit** is local weighted fit of the median, **firstder** is the first derivative of fit, and **secondder** is the second derivative of fit.

Plotting out fit produces two oscillations and then a steady increase in the data. Plotting the quartiles around that produces a large spread of data that narrows towards the increase in fit data. The first derivative shows the rate of change of the fit and this is where my issue comes in. I'm not sure where the increase in fit data starts based on the first derivative data. Logically, I know the signal-to-noise start date has to occur after March 7 (based on the quartiles), and before March 20 (before the steady increase in fit data). And this is also represented in the first derivative for about the same interval where the negative-to-positive inflection point changes on March 5th, becomes positive on March 16th, and then produces a stationary time series.

All that being said, should my exact start date be the change in the inflection point from the first derivative, or be the first positive value on March 16th?

I appreciate your time in this problem and any thoughts you may have!

```
data<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(1485950474, 1486036874, 1486123274, 
1486209674, 1486296074, 1486382474, 1486468874, 1486555274, 1486641674, 
1486728074, 1486814474, 1486900874, 1486987274, 1487073674, 1487160074, 
1487246474, 1487332874, 1487419274, 1487505674, 1487592074, 1487678474, 
1487764874, 1487851274, 1487937674, 1488024074, 1488110474, 1488196874, 
1488283274, 1488369674, 1488456074, 1488542474, 1488628874, 1488715274, 
1488801674, 1488888074, 1488974474, 1489060874, 1489147274, 1489233674, 
1489320074, 1489406474, 1489492874, 1489579274, 1489665674, 1489752074, 
1489838474, 1489924874, 1490011274, 1490097674, 1490184074, 1490270474, 
1490356874, 1490443274, 1490529674, 1490616074, 1490702474, 1490788874, 
1490875274, 1490961674, 1491048074, 1491134474, 1491220874, 1491307274, 
1491393674, 1491480074, 1491566474, 1491652874, 1491739274, 1491825674, 
1491912074, 1491998474, 1492084874, 1492171274, 1492257674, 1492344074, 
1492430474, 1492516874, 1492603274, 1492689674, 1492776074, 1492862474, 
1492948874, 1493035274, 1493121674, 1493208074, 1493294474, 1493380874, 
1493467274, 1493553674, 1493640074, 1493726474, 1493812874, 1493899274, 
1493985674, 1494072074, 1494158474, 1494244874, 1494331274, 1494417674, 
1494504074, 1494590474, 1494676874, 1494763274, 1494849674, 1494936074, 
1495022474, 1495108874, 1495195274, 1495281674, 1495368074), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Q25 = c(-1.61495132528742, -3.86616056128065, -3.92140420424278, 
-4.8011229557052, -8.64427034627082, -3.11323607034871, -4.3673083843457, 
-1.45023104534208, 0.395769745934938, -1.49394189431791, -3.54063822876105, 
-4.36090193633662, -0.966958995958447, -2.43233048854294, -0.181367797683111, 
0.826258942687981, 3.36833418895383, -6.8991417494414, -1.15773470862185, 
-1.75360705873163, 1.83790453304777, 2.11575746130393, -3.82025172988123, 
0.679651741170909, -4.64628184041103, -6.91923314565111, 0.550274303541761, 
0.104011128328036, -0.895257855280075, -0.801630235696042, 2.27958927430356, 
2.98003963398985, 3.41649824319921, 1.56559818977215, -2.20923132476973, 
0.552658760232765, 0.15158829140461, -4.75454688546242, -0.595460561248954, 
-2.53729443345183, -0.826010503400985, -5.20578683534568, -2.78364193219594, 
-3.62503323095109, 3.37820215582788, -2.53645164034493, -1.76051141957494, 
-1.0256290530567, 1.94178279643985, 0.261239031590387, 0.00321585342072063, 
2.87814873140354, -2.26732156613212, 2.65097224867168, -4.16746046231376, 
1.64816233695592, 3.50505415841016, 2.83685877611882, 1.66353660199615, 
2.27900517713667, 5.47721995923733, -5.31044894311933, 7.30753839733595, 
5.50143585044911, -1.25129055380416, -2.41051058119916, 3.69266303212359, 
2.28752278841533, -0.275687673398348, 5.74597173218469, 6.5773422259343, 
3.72096844335478, 2.05388534852328, 5.41063696868948, 0.526467452167141, 
1.60445671702256, -1.80394989627014, 1.56432488418924, 5.95370989889123, 
7.94953250403525, 4.09121878799004, 2.11516919787794, -2.12808005361608, 
6.77215849921842, 9.53718510298556, 4.16562173164636, 10.4573226478082, 
7.703077796612, 7.55811710979136, 4.47194951592662, 10.2104312432178, 
11.3454383477984, 0.997649090931488, 4.84898050707927, 10.8819209584302, 
8.06296236341084, 11.3317616787558, 7.51878628894305, 7.87729934765305, 
11.9108509727303, 6.77401202490232, 5.36297357453455, 10.6362047038983, 
8.68979831512869, 4.0465996534104, 11.9579904470733, 9.41141176380086, 
10.5754750604254, 12.6944336852953, 7.61563466861022), Q75 = c(5.93775779359077, 
26.4536084846094, 7.92690107568623, 16.195405687679, 3.47567054091916, 
34.9690262666155, 15.5126126583077, 24.4425589002446, 29.7425859431597, 
23.1420118192775, 26.827758017105, 18.6306368759596, 19.759179203689, 
10.0667740183259, 30.9080218485755, 10.0628623899296, 21.1120424008512, 
12.1232187464341, 14.9571040303508, 11.4927011052638, 16.1617172813173, 
19.0606972964125, 8.39991659547325, 9.5080530252195, 10.2717546026802, 
12.018391863395, 27.2666992661895, 12.5172584337237, 19.9658806224003, 
6.90019918091751, 18.4119063276997, 23.2991253786256, 27.95161418973, 
16.9477966472485, 26.3880458021082, 19.2178725103802, 5.58699033890406, 
9.82525729279156, 6.22139350667344, 5.6625294221828, 8.18283315939774, 
4.78856479855966, 4.91215612536983, 5.35278870440784, 15.7471499356884, 
7.95473965312171, 7.58463611165082, 6.03119890210746, 9.88624343762245, 
6.66377352843609, 6.92675024060609, 7.20403099201013, 6.96877369392089, 
17.7034248870798, 6.22890341708267, 6.1624397247754, 23.3856864094132, 
7.13518162203812, 6.96344109315883, 7.69414570220079, 18.0859103957135, 
7.52300478408242, 10.1635801549871, 10.021556657451, 8.51746254314866, 
7.83000625461296, 15.4938419153615, 8.6844260972191, 8.07596479745038, 
13.1423674521087, 8.04161364299224, 10.7442773622841, 8.58410892324644, 
9.08436532340561, 8.84748510783176, 9.27529549461203, 9.01978932806698, 
9.99776533859531, 9.61123990151036, 11.2228855544025, 10.3285714984086, 
10.7107229417799, 11.452541129334, 11.9951421202043, 11.3568792509498, 
11.139621487692, 12.957244784325, 13.1010906952192, 11.8445972599726, 
12.8124554609003, 12.1817389611984, 13.4529860098547, 13.1808997426024, 
12.568956945967, 13.9405958892683, 14.4445923505263, 14.5816203429081, 
12.798362023978, 13.7926596005317, 14.3284196983115, 14.3967490595795, 
14.3699332949429, 13.8061418130819, 15.4045229902535, 15.328632395916, 
15.5928587109464, 15.5111381098579, 15.7167488979248, 16.4121827249844, 
16.7700564366026), fit = c(1.3157822724014, 1.44491806546299, 
1.67963756121542, 1.96834398237369, 2.32222986513481, 2.73223146146706, 
3.16143742264514, 3.74278329406317, 4.4673163398484, 5.08529278937518, 
5.58735598987316, 6.01592790788482, 6.19893270175371, 6.0219082198616, 
5.64253432163072, 5.29694818196536, 4.89670493804841, 4.35145910275626, 
3.89449691453349, 3.48150649031492, 3.06858491643756, 2.88963188544926, 
3.13399806321574, 3.62311989322663, 4.03902573446563, 4.40598627768245, 
4.84291047423098, 5.1737840740012, 5.3972440468493, 5.5747020603732, 
5.62430591107552, 5.42843052467024, 5.07513358262307, 4.79108701506415, 
4.59907825712695, 4.39731440509327, 4.22559688081583, 4.10100609028878, 
4.00444369172723, 3.92144298531529, 3.82259220819525, 3.72499526558926, 
3.68395895980124, 3.69588308031619, 3.73924432798967, 3.84246487218137, 
4.07884774763199, 4.41108295888359, 4.70167312999791, 4.95537881350854, 
5.2206483181831, 5.42551590243433, 5.52148736399275, 5.55736071284688, 
5.60710852579646, 5.65757759073701, 5.68911425674423, 5.76594044238814, 
5.93786454015275, 6.15175825295678, 6.31743846502224, 6.40077523837882, 
6.45704948591979, 6.53019436816257, 6.59356685208809, 6.63353784524384, 
6.71356141899707, 6.88849022040772, 7.11437487009308, 7.30646639975639, 
7.43724432723552, 7.55279324817994, 7.67877181101032, 7.76924002146674, 
7.83161170884946, 7.97157625691941, 8.25223488219952, 8.60947602940562, 
8.95816992458796, 9.34076728750423, 9.77554331222275, 10.1411049362597, 
10.3842988541376, 10.5696053585185, 10.7520817841281, 10.9357595672387, 
11.0970528791622, 11.2495931571849, 11.3764752236255, 11.4864715266717, 
11.6317299424136, 11.8381584436134, 12.0667779318613, 12.2724056764894, 
12.462010561811, 12.6517333832877, 12.8101492769744, 12.9055352762602, 
12.9678598772259, 13.0582354099638, 13.1489397497677, 13.2204738414797, 
13.346284619515, 13.6054940294766, 13.9436193637562, 14.2337005769519, 
14.5449448398809, 14.8895799498019, 15.0551768009747, 15.0689572800127
), firstder = c(0.0542499277820437, 0.193160412687084, 0.264645386746196, 
0.318230646770668, 0.390583391620104, 0.410606699200811, 0.484714112557398, 
0.683182658658343, 0.699350916534123, 0.546311900646561, 0.476582322984034, 
0.33921923563074, 0.000346679118119919, -0.32275830659655, -0.377372654859586, 
-0.342379980870621, -0.492111485610006, -0.524917784293232, -0.414059192641829, 
-0.430018688265099, -0.343482693656914, 0.0295127267198723, 0.42189373253822, 
0.482044173095213, 0.364522990904745, 0.40991488301477, 0.40715895907959, 
0.264020778627613, 0.200548459021332, 0.136695124879259, -0.0667758528503706, 
-0.308783766357995, -0.344835056787729, -0.22338628389576, -0.19056674389956, 
-0.195775242472453, -0.146360055189657, -0.107867992742261, -0.0856184200473131, 
-0.0883963049921002, -0.106496806989568, -0.0747428483921662, 
-0.0103234284849929, 0.028493059030597, 0.0620691939868203, 0.163240621281308, 
0.304123951137378, 0.325609827601989, 0.261609166722046, 0.261432729205552, 
0.249586474110962, 0.150199026157553, 0.0521536950613295, 0.0370628072573624, 
0.0565243651980056, 0.0371337817771211, 0.0409727028064402, 0.124422569131023, 
0.207609809433488, 0.20232516927351, 0.121600832063498, 0.058433044321534, 
0.0638003776220697, 0.0745713396178918, 0.0471802520722933, 0.0467708263829785, 
0.126045851395065, 0.213953247074989, 0.220308792495525, 0.158550331399022, 
0.11422743390592, 0.123806714974779, 0.114997378074604, 0.0651990840907102, 
0.0828996021118185, 0.210617558388392, 0.336478451788591, 0.356675237198802, 
0.354610868118913, 0.419333862640583, 0.419974858146042, 0.301270480481834, 
0.201419853206041, 0.17882844049566, 0.186628379656891, 0.172934534594114, 
0.156583940148236, 0.142289490196014, 0.11234075824169, 0.119081439314575, 
0.177295034391252, 0.226764155293772, 0.22057696671022, 0.193643700730051, 
0.190744241252391, 0.181381161962744, 0.127949080877661, 0.0681406193708671, 
0.0729227267768433, 0.0983314755975622, 0.0766175682172481, 0.0819140886989596, 
0.188151474480757, 0.320764600927798, 0.32011829707578, 0.283266397091015, 
0.351814702578002, 0.276441515194414, 0.0724489974588587, -0.0273030060468944
), secondder = c(0.172623240328004, 0.105197729482076, 0.0377722186361492, 
0.0693983014127931, 0.0753071882860794, -0.0352605731246656, 
0.18347539983784, 0.213461692364051, -0.181125176612492, -0.124952855162631, 
-0.0145063001624228, -0.260219874544165, -0.417525238481075, 
-0.228684732948264, 0.119456036422192, -0.0494706884442619, -0.249992321034509, 
0.184379723668058, 0.037337459634748, -0.0692564508812885, 0.242328440097658, 
0.503662400655915, 0.281099610980781, -0.160798729866795, -0.0742436345141417, 
0.165027418734192, -0.170539266604553, -0.1157370942994, -0.0112075449131641, 
-0.116499123370982, -0.290442832088276, -0.193572994926973, 0.121470414067507, 
0.12142713171643, -0.055788051724031, 0.0453710545782453, 0.0534593199873461, 
0.0235248049074466, 0.0209743404824492, -0.0265301103720232, 
-0.00967089362291196, 0.0731788108177152, 0.0556600289966314, 
0.0219729460345484, 0.0451793238778984, 0.157163530711077, 0.124603129001063, 
-0.081631376071841, -0.0463699456880455, 0.0460170706550578, 
-0.0697095808442372, -0.129065315062581, -0.0670253471298663, 
0.0368435715219322, 0.0020795443593542, -0.0408607112011232, 
0.0485385532597613, 0.118361179389404, 0.0480133012155273, -0.058582581535485, 
-0.102866092884539, -0.0234694825993884, 0.0342041492004599, 
-0.0126622252088158, -0.0421199498823812, 0.0413010985037516, 
0.117248951520421, 0.0585658398394289, -0.045854748998357, -0.0776621731946507, 
-0.0109836217915529, 0.0301421839292724, -0.0477608577296227, 
-0.0518357302381656, 0.0872367662803821, 0.168199146272765, 0.0835226405276321, 
-0.0431290697072093, 0.039000331547431, 0.0904456574959092, -0.0891636664849909, 
-0.148245088843424, -0.0514561657081618, 0.00627334028739845, 
0.00932653803506511, -0.036714228160621, 0.00401303926886598, 
-0.0326019391733094, -0.0272955247353401, 0.0407768868811118, 
0.0756503032722406, 0.0232879385327998, -0.0356623156999039, 
-0.0182042162604343, 0.012405297305115, -0.0311314558844096, 
-0.0757327062857556, -0.0438842167278324, 0.0534484315397847, 
-0.00263093389834701, -0.0407968808622812, 0.0513899218257041, 
0.161084849737891, 0.10414140315619, -0.105434010860225, 0.0317302108906947, 
0.105366400083279, -0.256112774850456, -0.151872260620654, -0.0476317463908522
)), row.names = c(NA, -110L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is to find where the fit column starts rising then fit a curve made up of a horizontal line segment followed by a sloped line segment (red in the graph) and report the changepoint (Date0 and dashed line in graph).

```
# calculate starting values, st
fm0 <- lm(fit ~ Date, data, subset = seq(to = nrow(data), length = 20))
st <- c(mean(data$fit[1:20]), coef(fm0))
names(st) <- c("a0", "a", "b")

fm <- nls(fit ~ pmax(a0, a + b * as.numeric(Date)), data, start = st)

# solve a0 = a + b * Date0 for Date0 using calculated a0, a and b
Date0 <- with(as.list(coef(fm)), .POSIXct((a0 - a)/b))

plot(fit ~ Date, data, ylab = "")
lines(fitted(fm) ~ Date, data, col = "red")
abline(v = Date0, lty = 2)

Date0
## [1] "2017-03-21 07:53:56 EDT"
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I think this is really neat but I need to involve how the pick up the signal from the noise based on the derivatives.